# Images only display on initial loading of ASP.MVC page

Tags: html, image, model-view-controller, redirect, layout

In the _Layout.cshtml, I have a heading image and two link images that change into other images when the cursor hovers over them. When the page is loaded initially (e.g. //localhost:58055/), the images are shown. When I redirect through the links so that the URL is //localhost:58055/Home/Index, for instance, the images  only show the little "broken image" icon. Why might this be? Here is where I specify the header's image in _Layout.cshtml.

```
    <header>
        <div class="trippy-title">
            <img src="images/title_wider.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" repeat>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read this article for a better understanding of locations in ASP.net.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

as a simple solution you can use ~/images/title_wider.jpg this works with Razor 2+